# How to remove unnecessary padding in ion-item with ion input in ionic-3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How to remove unnecessary padding in ion-item with ion input in ionic-3 ?

```
<ion-row align-items-center>
   <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
   <ion-col text-right  no-padding col-4.5> 
      Canister Width <p>(C.W.)</p>:
   </ion-col>
   <ion-col no-lines ion-item no-padding>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove a padding from `item` in the tag with the `ion-item` attribute because it's not the `ion-item` who has a padding, but the `item-inner` child who is generated inside.

That's why `no-padding` doesn't works, but you can simply do this with css like this

```
.item .item-inner {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this ?

```
 <ion-row align-items-center no-padding>
```

or you can add `<div no-padding>`
?

Answer (score 0):

add below code into your css

```
ion-item{padding:0 !important}
```

or

you can add inline css in HTML file

```
<ion-row align-items-center>
   <ion-col style="padding:0"> 
      Canister Width <p>(C.W.)</p>:
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```